# Need design ideas: Searchable time/datetime for C# and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am trying to add a feature on one of my applications. Here is a sample:

**Company ABC**

```
Business hours:
Sunday closed
Monday 7am - 5pm
Tuesday 7am - 5pm
Wednesday 7am - 5pm
Thursday 7am - 5pm
Friday 7am - 5pm
Saturday closed
```

**Company DEF**

```
Sunday 10am - 12pm
Monday 8am - 4pm
Tuesday 8am - 4pm
Wednesday 8am - 4pm
Thursday 8am - 4pm
Friday 8am - 4pm
Saturday closed
```

Now, what I want to do is to have my users be able to search/filter the business hours. For example, only return businesses who are open during Monday 2PM, or Saturday 1PM, or Monday any time.

My idea is to use datetime in SQL Server, but it appears I may need to create 7 columns for each day (Sunday to Saturday) and different columns for Starting time to open to Closing time to open.

The next idea is to make these columns searchable such that I will be able to filter them. for example, if a user searches for Monday 12PM, the search will be Monday (open time) <= (user search, 12pm) <= (close time).

So basically, it will be similar to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Companies 
WHERE [user_search_time] IS "BETWEEN open_time AND close_time WHERE day=[user_search_day]
```

I'm having a hard time designing this, let alone how to implement it.

Technology used is C#/ASP.Net and SQL Server 2008.
The problem is how to design/implement this feature using the technologies mentioned above.

Any idea/tips will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to push this to codereview, or programmers.  I think you are on the right path, but instead of adding columns, add a new table.  called `business_hours`

```
BUSINESS_HOURS
business (company fk)
open_time (datetime)
close_time (datetime)
day (M,T,W,TH,F,S,Sun) // you can do this however u want 1-7 would work as well
```

Then your query is almost the same as what you have.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    business_hours 
WHERE 
    business = user_company_id
    [user_search_time] IS BETWEEN open_time AND close_time and 
    day=[user_search_day]
```

Benefits to a table is it's more denormalized and you could support hours that have breaks in them.  I could suport 12-2 as well as 5-8.  You would just insert a new record and it would work.  I am not a big fan of doing `all day` by doing a range from 12AM to 12PM but it will work, and keep your design simple.